# How to download image synchronously in background?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have a background worker which I use to get some data from a web server.
It's required to download some images (png or jpg) also.
But every time I try to create BitmapImage or WriteableBitmap in the background worker thread I get Invalid cross-thread access
Is it ever possible to load image in background not UI thread?

Comment: sorry thought it was about android, ignore this comment. How do I delete comments anyway?

Comment: Perhaps you might make clear why you think you need a background worker to do this at all. Creating a `BitmapImage` and specifying a URL for it doesn't block the thread while the image downloads.  That is already implemented by the framework as an asynchronous operation.  So its not clear to me why you need to do stuff "synchronously in background"?

Comment: I'm writing a library which retrives some information from a web server. I want it to make able to save all the data to sterling database to make it possible to restore and last retrived data even if there's no internet connection. So, I just run the library to gather all information and store it to Sterling in a background worker. It should also be possible to use this library in scheduled task

Comment: The classes you are trying use are designed to be only used from the UI (Dispatcher) thread, so you either have to marshall back onto the UI thread or store the image data in a raw format and only creating this controls as and when required from the UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

use this it will work for you.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    //write here whatever you want to update on screen.
                    textblock.Text = "text changed";
                    // just like this line changed the text of a textblock
                });
```

if it does not work paste your code.

Comment: @user924780 nope it is not a workaround. The issue is that you cannot access objects located in other threads, which will lead to exceptions. There are several ways to do cross thread calls, this one is perfectly fine.

Comment: @oleksii It's strange, why it's located in UI thread when I create the object it in background? The line `var image = new WritableBitmap(100, 100)` throws the exception

Comment: @Sheldon:  In Silverlight all UI oriented classes are specifically limited to the main UI thread.  An attempt to even construct such an class on a background thread will result in an exception.  BTW __Even__ if you could execute the constructor the resulting object would be useless to you, you would never be able to include it in the Silverlight VisualTree.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones thanks, it's clear now. The only option for me now is to download and keep the image as byte array (

Comment: @Shedon: well that actually makes sense.  I don't think I would want to keep instances of UI classes (with all the extra overhead that implies) even if I could.  I'd keep in the background/cache/DB the simplest representation of it, only hydrating it to UI element when about to use it.  Bear in mind that a downloaded image stream will be in a compressed format and using imagetools you can even convert the pixel array in a WriteableBitmap to a PNG for storage purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In `DoWork` method of BackgroundWorker you can't access to controls, created in main thread, but in that method you can pass downloaded image to `RunWorkerCompleted` event method, because this event run on thread where you create BackgroundWorker (in most cases it's main thread).

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundworker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundworker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundworker_DoWork);
backgroundworker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundworker_RunWorkerCompleted);


static void backgroundworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //download image and make Image class instance
    e.Result = //assign your image here
}

static void backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Image i = (e.Result as Image);
    //assign image to your control
}
```